# python: should decorator names be actions or descriptions?

Tags: python, coding-style, decorator

Say I have a decorator which causes the function to print out any exceptions and return None, if an exception happens, instead of failing. Assuming this is a good idea, what's the preferred naming style?

a)

```
@ignore_exceptions
def foobar(a, b, c):
    raise ValueError("This function always fails...")
```

b)

```
@ignores_exceptions
def foobar(a, b, c):
    raise ValueError("This function always fails...")
```

That is: should it `a)` be a command (the decorator *tells* the function to do something different), or `b)` a description (the decorator lets the progammer know an attribute of the function)?

Comment: Well, b) is going to print out a NameError, because there's probably no such type as "ValeuError". :) But that's not a serious point.

Comment: @abarnert: hah, indeed =P. fixed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the active version (`ignore_exceptions`) is more used than the descriptive version (`ignores_exceptions`), at least in the Python code bases that I'm familiar with.

The PEP 8 guideline does have a section on [naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) but it does not offer much help in this case. In any case, consistency across your code base is the most important thing.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that `ignore_exceptions` is better here, simply based on what I am seeing in the [PythonDecoratorLibrary](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) page.

Some example decorator names used there are `countcalls` and `dump_args`, which is more consistent with `ignore_exceptions` than `ignores_exceptions`.

Consistency is really the only reason to choose one over the other, since both make it clear what is happening.

Comment: Actually, looking over the examples there, it looks like most of them are descriptions (property, memoized, curried, etc.)—except in the case where there's an obvious action verb, in which case they use that (countcalls, apply, etc.). Which isn't that consistent—but if you want to be consistent with that, I guess ignore_exceptions is better.